# How to display multiple columns (2) as one using Bootstrap when shrinking screen (responsive)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a design with twelve columns. On larger screens I want to display

```
col-md4 + col-md2 + col-md2 + col-md 2 + col-md2.
```

When using smaller screens I want to display

- `col-md4` in one row,
- two `col-md2s` in the second row
- and another two `col-md2s` in the last row.

How do I do this using bootstrap?

I have uploaded an image of how I picture this, as the description might be confusing. :)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2FRs.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bootstrap's grid system is mobile-first, you should look at it the other way, and analyse it from the small size upwards.
What I would do is:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.